# calling an expression in the document in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

Say I have the following function which I would like to plot.

```
$S(z)=\frac{p.(\alpha_H+z.\alpha_W)}{p.(\alpha_H+z.\alpha_W)+\beta_H+z.\beta_W}$
```

While I could specify it in the `\addplot` command, I was just wondering whether there might be a more efficient method where I could label it in some sense (since it is already mentioned in the document) and call it by a macro.

In fact I would like to see how it changes by differing values of the parameters additionally.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to plot a function which is prepared for math typesetting. You will need to replicate the function by means of something like

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{S}{1}{\valueP * (\alphaH + \valueZ * \alphaW) / (\valueP*(\alphaH + \valueZ * \alphaW) + \betaH + \valueZ * \betaW)}
```

with

```
\def\alphaH{4}
\def\alphaW{5}
...
```

you can also declare a function with more than one argument instead of defining constants.